# jade/pug not detecting javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

So after I click the chapter link, it shows in the console that the data is loaded into the commentList variable as an array using an ajax get call. And jade is supposed to loop through the array and display it. But when I go to inspect element it shows an empty p element. Why? If i remove the if statement and just go with each loop, it says commentList is undefined.

Here's my js file:

```
var type = 1, //circle type - 1 whole, 0.5 half, 0.25 quarter
    radius = '20em', //distance from center
    start = -90, //shift start from 0
    $elements = $('li:not(:first-child)'),
    numberOfElements = (type === 1) ?  $elements.length : $elements.length - 1, //adj for even distro of elements when not full circle
    slice = 360 * type / numberOfElements;

$elements.each(function(i) {
    var $self = $(this),
        rotate = slice * i + start,
        rotateReverse = rotate * -1;

    $self.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)' + 
                 ' translate(' + radius + ')' +
                 ' rotate(' + rotateReverse + 'deg)' + 
                 ' translate(-50%, -50%)'
});


});



/* $('.fade').on('click', function() {
   $('.centered li').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(1500)

      })
  }) */

$('.centered li:not(:first-child').each(function(i){


        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(1500)

      })

$('#userRole').click(function(){
    if($('#userRole').is(':checked')){
        $('#passCode').show();
    }else {
        $('#passCode').hide();
    };    
 });


/*
function getChapterLinks(chapterId) {

   var datta;

    $.ajax({
      url: chapterId
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   datta = data;

    });
    console.log(datta)
return datta
}

*/
var datta;
var link;
var toglink;
var commentList;
var commentChap;
$( "a#chapterLinks1" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  link = $(this).attr('href');
  //console.log(link);
 /* var datta = $.ajax({
      url: link

    })
  //console.log(datta)
  dik = datta;

*/
  toglink = link.replace('/chapterLinks', '/checktoggle')
  $.get(toglink, function(data){

      datta = data;

  })

  $.get(link, function(data){
    commentList = data.commentList;
    commentChap = data.chapter[0]._id;
    console.log('hi chapid' + data.chapter[0]._id)
    console.log(commentList);
    console.log(commentChap);


  })



/*
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.font = "30px Arial";
   ctx.fillText(data.chapter[0].chapterStory,10,50);
*/
});


 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  $.get(link, function(data){

       //var story = data.chapter[0].chapterStory;
       console.log(data)
       console.log(commentList)
       modal.find('.modal-title').text(data.chapter[0].chapterTitle.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
       modal.find('.modal-body').text(data.chapter[0].chapterStory.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
       $('#chapid').val(data.chapter[0]._id);


       if(datta.togg == true){
         document.getElementById("toggle-heart").checked = true;
       }else{
        document.getElementById("toggle-heart").checked = false;
       }

      //$('body').append(data);
  })

})


  $("#likeform").on("change", "input:checkbox", function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
   /* var datta;
    $.get(link, function(data){

          //console.log(data);  
          datta = data;
          console.log(datta);
      }) */


    var formdata = $('#likeform').serialize();
    console.log(formdata);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uplikes',
        data: formdata,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){



            if(datta.user == null){
              //$("body").html(data);
              document.location.href = '/login';
              console.log(data)
            }
            else{
            console.log(data);
          }
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

          console.log(errorThrown);
        }

      })

    })


    $('#comForm').on("submit", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var formdata = $(this).closest('form').serialize();  
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/add-comment',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(data);
            commentList = data.commentList;
            console.log(commentList);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

          console.log(errorThrown);
        }


      })


    })
```

Here's my jade file:

```
  doctype html
  html
  head

  body(style='background-color:black')





  p 
   each chapter in chapters
    ul.centered
      li.none
      li 

       a#chapterLinks1(href='/chapterLinks/'+chapter._id, data-toggle='modal', data-target='#myModal') Chapter #{chapter.chapterNumber} 
        br
        img.center(src='/images/chapter' + chapter.chapterNumber + '.jpg',  height='70', width='70')






   div.menuchapters 
    if (!user) 
        a(href='/main', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Back to Main
        br
        a(href='/login', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Login
        br
        a(href='/register', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Register
        br

    if (user)
        a Welcome #{user.name}
        br
        a(href='/main', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Back to Main
        br
        a(href='/chapters' , style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Add Chapters
        br
        a(href='/profile', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Profile
        br
        a(href='/logout', style='text-decoration:none;color:gray;') Logout


// Modal
#myModal.modal.custom.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='myModalLabel')
  .modal-dialog(role='document')
    .model-content
      .modal-header
        h4#myModalLabel.modal-title 
      .modal-body
        h4#myModalLabel.modal-body 
      .modal-footer
        form.like-icon(role='form', action='/uplikes', method='post', id='likeform')
            input(type='hidden', name='by', id='inpurUserId', value=user ? user.id: '' placeholder='user', autofocus)
            input(type='hidden', name='chapterId', id='chapid', placeholder='user', autofocus)
            input#toggle-heart(type='checkbox')
            label(for='toggle-heart') ❤

        div#messages
          if commentList                                    
            each comment in commentList
                div.comment__item
                    div.infos
                        img(src= '../' +comment.by.profile_pic)
                    div.content
                        h3.comment__authorname #{comment.by.name}
                        b.comment__time #{moment(comment.createdAt, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()}
                        p #{comment.body}
          else
            p #{commentList}
        form(role='form', action='/add-comment', method='post', id='comForm')
                textarea(name='body', cols='30', rows='5', form="comForm", placeholder="Enter comment")
                br
                input(type='text', name='chapterId', id='inpurUserId', value='5a0f1e266b34a0212ccc0e5c', placeholder='chapter', hidden, autofocus)
                br
                input(type='text', name='by', id='inpurUserId', value=user ? user.id: '' placeholder='user', hidden, autofocus)
                button(type='submit') Add Comment




    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js')

      link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")

  script(src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js")
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  script(src='/javascripts/index.js')
```

Comment: Pffff seriously... nobody is going to go through 200 lines of code :/ Try to narrow it down

Comment: And then people complain I dont give enough lol. I did narrow it down in the description. Scoll to the div#messages commentList in the jade section. And then in the JS section:   $.get(link, function(data){
    commentList = data.commentList;

Comment: I guess jade loads vaiable once and renders it so I had to use jquery to append the new data and styles. Well thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that **Jade/Pug runs on server and creates the html for rendering**. This rendered html can contain css or js also for that matter but that's the main idea.

Jade/Pug can use variables that are available on the server when you call the methods to render/compile it. Once the html response has been created, its job is done.

Now you have an html file (which may include js/jquery files) that will be shown in your browser and your JS/jQuery scripts will be run on the browser. Jade does not do anything now when you are on browser side.